# Change CRS, but the image position also changing

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have 2 overlapped image, one is an aerial photo in CRS EPSG (4326) WGS 84, and one is a satellite image, in CRS EPSG:32648 WGS 84/UTM zone 48N. 
[image]

I need to georeference the aerial photo compare to satellite image, and to do so I need them in same CRS. However, when I change/save as the aerial photo CRS to UTM zone 48, it moves somewhere else, not overlapped anymore with the satellite image like below (when I zoom full, satellite image is in the right upper corner, meanwhile the aerial photo is somewhere else)

[image]

I tried the other way around, change the satellite CRS, also they not overlapped anymore.
Is there is any way to resolve this issue so when i change the CRS they kees overlapped?

Comment: How did you change the CRS? You can't just attach a new CRS into an image and say that it is now in a new coordinate system. Or you can and it is reasonable if image had a wrong CRS set by accident. Raster - Conversion - Translate in QGIS can do that for you. But for reprojecting an image from one system into another one the right tool is Raster - Projections - Warp.